# Mirroring output to element 14 7" touchscreen and hdmi

Tags: hdmi, pi-4, touchscreen

I would like to have the touchscreen and hdmi displays mirrored but I can't find any info or setting to mirror. Running Raspbian Buster and using an element 14 7" touchscreen.

Edit: I got mirroring to work using

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --same-as DIS-1`

but the resolutions are still messed up. I would like fullscreen to work on both displays but when I go fullscreen it shows right on HDMI but the touchscreen just shows the top left corner of the video.

Edit 2: Forcing HDMI resolution to same as touch screen helps but now when I go fullscreen in VLC video only shows on HDMI

Answer (score 0):

`xrandr --output DSI-1 --same-as  --output HDMI-1 --scale-from 800x600`

This properly mirrors my 800x600 touch screen through HDMI output to my vans entertainment center at an acceptable resolution for the kids to watch movies!! I can stream youtube videos or plex media full screen on both outputs. Now if I can just get VLC or something to play local video files properly on both screens.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.